# New inbox item not appearing when clicking on it

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, ios-app

I have this inbox item:

> [image: new answer]

I tap it and scroll down and see no answers:

> [image: nothing to see here]

nothing in the site either. maybe they deleted the answer but I don't want the tease of a possible answer if there's none.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it seems this doesn't work as I thought it worked on the regular site. So this seems a bug indeed.

Comment: @PatrickHofman well, it's weird. In case of a deleted question, [notification is being kept](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cx4nr.png) - in case of deleted answer, notifications are gone e.g. notification about your comment on your answer below vanished from my inbox.

Comment: Okay, so there is some inconsistency in the handling of such events. Did you notice any difference between the site and the app?

Comment: @PatrickHofman added a Codepen for easy testing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157329/upside-down-threejs-webgl-globe

Comment: This has to do with the way the app merges new content into the existing list.  It only adds new items without attempting to prune missing ones.  I'll have to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in 1.4.3.3.

The problem was that the app handled all paging stores in an additive way.  That is, inbox items would be added when observed but not deleted when they disappeared.  Now when you first open the inbox from a cold launch or pull to refresh it will load the first page and discard all old data.