# Deleted question still shows up in favorites

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, bookmarks

In the iOS app under the Puzzling community I have a favorite for "Steering the SS Puzzleship".  This question no longer appears in the list of Questions.  It still shows up under Favorites.

This question **does not** appear in my favorites if I view it on the *website*.

iOS 7.1.2
Stack Exchange 1.3.1 04/17/2015

[image: Question in favorites]
[image: Question not found]

Comment: Open the side menu and scroll above your username to find the version number, or scroll to the bottom of the menu and tap About.

Comment: Thank you @grgarside.  Question has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.3.3 in January.

This was caused by the same issue as [New inbox item not appearing when clicking on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256327/new-inbox-item-not-appearing-when-clicking-on-it/271799) where the store wasn't properly set up for removing items.  Now every time the first page of favorite items loads, it will discard the previously fetched pages.